# What does it mean to decorate with an argument in Python?

Tags: python, python-decorators

In Python I know a little about decorators.
In my poor understanding a decorated funtion declaration returns whatever the decorator function constructs with the original function (most reasonably this should be a callable):

```
def deco(func):
    def func_wrapper(name):
        return func(name)+", how are you?"
    return func_wrapper

@deco
def foo(name):
    return "Hello "+name

print(foo("Michael"))
```

This gives:

```
Hello Michael, how are you?
```

But what if a decorator is specified along with an argument:

```
def deco2(info):
    def info_decorator(func):
        def func_wrapper(name):
            return func(name) + info
        return func_wrapper
    return info_decorator

@deco2(", how are you?")
def foo2(name):
    return "Hello "+name

print(foo2("Regina"))
```

giving

```
Hello Regina, how are you?
```

What is the "rule" for handling this decorator?
It *seems*, that instead of returning `foo2` Python first calls `deco2` with the given arg, and ***assumes***, that this call first constructs a factory for a decorator, which then acts like before with foo2 passed to it in order to return the final wrapper. However, in this case there is one additional "*layer*" involved (three defs instead of two), which makes it hard for me, to identify the general rule.

Comment: Your second decorator will be equivalent to: `foo2 = deco2(", how are you?")(foo2)` placed after `foo2`.

Comment: I know, but in the first case it would just be: `foo = deco(foo)` placed after foo. Is it the argument in the decorator from which Python knows to add the additional indirection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you apply the decorator *without* arguments, e.g. `@foo`, then the decorator takes the function being decorated as its argument and is expected to return any callable that will replace the decorated function.

If you apply the decorator *with* arguments, e.g. `@foo('bar')`, then the decorator is expected to return a callable that will take the decorated function as its argument and return and callable that will replace the decorated function.

Put another way: a decorator without arguments only needs the function being decorated, but a decorator with arguments needs its own arguments *and* it needs to get a hold of the function being decorated somehow. Since the arguments to the decorator are arbitrary and not restricted in any way, it's hard to come up with any non-restrictive rules on how to additionally pass the decoratee to it as well. In that case the two-step process is applied: get decorator arguments, then return another callable that takes the decoratee.